# How do I set text width in CiviMail?

Tags: email

I have centered text in a mailing that I'm setting up. The line length is too long for easy readability. How do I set up a maximum text width? Here's how it looks now:[image]

Answer (score 2):

Insert a table with one row and one column and choose the desired width of the column when creating the table. Paste your plain text into the table - not an image with text, which will not appear correctly in some e-mail programs.

Comment: I tried using Joe's suggestion but couldn't make it work for me. I'm a newbie at HTML so this is a challenge! Elsewhere I found:Thanks, but I didn't like how the border looked on the text box.

Comment: Sheesh please ignore previous comment, I wasn't finished editing and it timed out. I didn't like how the border looked on the text box. I tried using Joe's suggestion but couldn't make it work for me. I'm a newbie at HTML so slogging through this is a challenge! Elsewhere I found adding " !important " worked, but that moved the centered copy block to the left. Sigh. I'll probably send this out all align:left, unless anyone else has suggestions?

Comment: Can you make the border transparent?

Comment: As I mentioned - newbie here - I don't know how to make the border transparent.

Comment: To make border transparent, right click in the table, select Table Properties, set Border size to 0

Answer (score 0):

```
<td style="max-width:200px;">
```

is the safest way. You cannot floating text over a table background image in Outlook (which is still a huge user base). It's not difficult: it's impossible. Better to use graphic text and repeat in alt tag.

Comment: (the post above ate the actual HTML reference)
Set the td tag style attribute max-width to whatever size you need is the safest way. You cannot floating text over a table background image in Outlook (which is still a huge user base). It's not difficult: it's impossible. Better to use graphic text and repeat in alt tag

Comment: I fixed by using the {} formatter to show the code

Comment: Joe - my answer, above, assumed that the 1 x 1 table,inserted below the cool flower image, would have the plain text that is below the image, not an image in the table.  Which is how I would do it. Just to clarify. I'll update my answer.

Comment: A friend set this up for me, so I'm good for now. Thanks for participating in this adventure in HTML!